# How to use string values from one array as indexes for another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference, associative-array

I've splitted a string into array, giving a delimitator. So, this new array created, will contain *values* that I would want to use as *indexes* for another given array.

Having a situation like this:

```
// my given array
$array['key1']['key2']['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key'] = 'blablabl';

// the value of my given array
$value = $array['key1']['key2']['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key'];

$string = "key1;key2";
$keys = explode(";", $string);
```

I want to call dinamically (during the execution of my PHP script) the value of the given array, but, using as *indexes* all the values of the array `$keys`, and in addition appending the *indexes* `['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key']` of my given array.

I hope I have been clear.
Many thanks.

Comment: You want to build an array whose nesting level is dynamically determined by the length of `$keys`?

Comment: Show us your code - how you tried to achieve what you want

Comment: I have that '$keys'. I want to use all that values as indexes in the '$array' to call a particular value from '$array'.

Comment: So what doesn't work? Based on your last comment (at least the way I understand your problem), you've got the solution already. Please explain what's not working.

Comment: I want to put that indexes dinamically. I don't want to write them manually as `[$keys[0]][$keys[1]]` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you have to use references. Below code should work as you expect:

```
<?php

    $string = "key1;key2;key3;key4";
    $keys = explode(";", $string);


    $array['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key'] = 'blablabl';

    $ref = & $array;                               

    for ($i=0, $c = count($keys); $i<$c ; ++$i) {   
        $ref = &$ref[$keys[$i]];       
    }

    echo $ref['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key'];

    $value = $ref['a_given_key']['some_other_given_key'];

    echo $value;


?>
```

I would like to add that just after using reference you should unset it using:

```
unset($ref);
```

If you don't do this and many lines later you run for example `$ref = 2;` it will modify your source array so you have to remember about unsetting references just after it's no longer in use.

Comment: what have you done it's precisely what I'm looking for! Thanks! :)